# Grease pencil problem, Can't see the keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil

So it's bugging me a lot right now, I can't seemed to see the keyframe added in grease pencil but it's animating, now I can't move and copy certain keyframes, any fixed for this? is this a bug?

Comment: Can you send a pic?? You can also try right clicking on timeline and selecting keyframes

Comment: See Josh's answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251442/why-do-grease-pencil-keyframes-show-up-in-the-dope-sheet-grease-pencil-mode-b/251477#251477

Answer (score 1):

You won't see the keyframes in the timeline. Instead you have to use Dope Sheet > Grease Pencil.