# Why do Grease Pencil keyframes show up in the Dope Sheet (Grease Pencil mode), but not in the Timeline?

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil, dopesheet

[image]
Are grease pencil object keyframes not the same as normal keyframes?

[image: keyframes question]

Comment: I'm not so sure, but maybe try maximizing the timeline by pressing ctrl+spacebar when hovering over the timeline, and try scrolling all the way up?
Maybe it's just a scrolled down view you have there? idk

Comment: Please add the blend file ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they're quite different entities, as standard keyframes store only simple numeric values of a channel, while GP keyframes store all drawing informations.

This is the reason why they have their own editor (they don't even appear in the standard dopesheet window).